# Reference to an item in a data object

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

I have a GetItems method that looks like this:

---

```
public SampleDataItem GetItem(string uniqueId)
{
        // Simple linear search is acceptable for small data sets
        var matches = _sampleDataSource.AllGroups.SelectMany(group => group.Items).Where((item) => item.UniqueId.Equals(uniqueId));
        if (matches.Count() == 1) return matches.First();
       return null;
}
```

---

When I reference the object that returns, it is not a pointer to the actual item that I have in my data object, and therefore will not update.  Is there a better way to access a reference to the item in my data object?

Comment: What do you mean by it not being a pointer to the actual item?

Answer (score 0):

Normally this works:

```
 private List<Person> _persons = new List<Person> 
        {
            new Person{Age=23,Name="Ram"},
             new Person{Age=43,Name="Rahim"}
        };



 private Person GetPerson(int age)
        {
            return _persons.Where(p => p.Age == age).FirstOrDefault();
        }

 Person p = GetPerson(23);
            p.Name = "Hari";
```

it changes the name of the first item.